# Getting url with # in django

Tags: python, django

How can I catch all urls for `/accounts/social/connections/*` using django?

Comment: # is a reserved character, you cant use it in your url patterns

Comment: read more [here](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-writing)

Answer (score 0):

Add link of app urls.py in project urls.py url(r'^$', include('main_app.urls')), and write the urls in your app directory in urls.py.

Comment: the idea was to redirect all /* to one view in the url but I've just used a javascript redirect in the template

Comment: You have to learn more about django , use professional solves. Search more. Good luck . ))